# what's the absolute path to refer files in ember-cli tests/?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Like I can include any file in `app/` with `import Something from '<app_name>/...'`, what's the corresponding thing for files in `tests/`?

Now I always use relative path but sometimes it's quite annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<app-name>/tests/` and you should be set

Answer (score 1):

FYI, If you are testing from an Addon you will need `dummy` as your app-name for example `dummy/tests/`